# The Official Stack Overflow Bunny

Tags: discussion, waffles

Messrs. and Mesdames,

I, Chacha, would like to ask the community of Stack Overflow to acknowledge the following bunny as the official Stack Overflow bunny. This bunny has been responsible for many funny threads, and has been involved in countless efforts to bring laughter to the programming world.

There is no reasonable explanation for why this bunny should not be crowned the Stack Overflow bunny, as he bears a waffle on his head. Such a sign of excellency should not in any way be ignored, but instead recognized throughout the mighty Trilogy.

I give you **the bunny**:

[image: THE bunny]

([full size](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0e/Oolong_the_Rabbit%27s_last_performance_%282003%29.jpg))

If anyone can see a reason that this bunny should not be granted the title **Stack Overflow Bunny**, speak now or forever hold your peace.

If not, may the unicorns across this land all acknowledge the greatness of this bunny, and may they forever live in harmony!

**Update**: After 17 hours of no objections, in the power vested in me by the ..... I hereby declare this bunny to be the **Official Stack Overflow Bunny**.

Comment: I thought the waffle *was* the Stack Overflow crown.

Comment: Awww... Oolong. I love Oolong.

Comment: Looks 'shopped to me....Just saying.

Comment: @Justin: Truthfully, I've also always felt that way about this *particular* image, but every other Oolong image where he's balancing something looks totally fine. I guess there's just something about the shadows in this one that bug me.

Comment: @gnovice I don't like the shadows, and where are his/her ears?

Comment: Bunny overflow? Also, the pic doesnt load

Comment: @RadekS Doesn't load for me either, but based on the file name I suspect it's this image: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Oolong_last_head_performance.jpg

Comment: You missed half the salutation, @Pop.

Comment: That's odd. I wasn't even typing at the beginning. I must have hit `CTRL` + `DEL` by accident when the page loaded? Anyways, fixed. (@Grace) Okay, after replacing it, it's disappeared _again_. What is going on here? Can you try fixing it, @Grace? It seems to be stripping those first words out, for me.

Comment: @Pop Oh, it was auto, not manual. Go fig, it's [the new salutation stripper](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/93989#93989). I guess it does trigger on edit. In that case, it'll probably be wise just to remove the rest of the salutation.

Comment: Ah, another new feature that works on save but doesn't automatically go back and fix old posts. That makes sense. It's too timid to touch "Messrs." by itself, at least. (@Grace)

Comment: We need a unicorn, not a bunny.

Answer (score 55):

When you consider the original *uncropped* image, you can see that Oolong was **fated** to be the chosen SO bunny!

[image]

**SO bunny be praised!!!**

Comment: Why do the damn waffles always land butter side down?

Comment: The waffles never land. They hover over SO bunny's head forever and ever. Amen.

Comment: I stand corrected.  That would make it much easier to pick the bunny hairs off.  Mmm, waffles.  And some lapin avec citron for dessert.

Comment: Why do those waffles look so much like slices of brains? There must be something wrong with me.

Answer (score 27):

Why not choose one of Jeff's *bunnies*?

[image]

That photo was taken at StackOverflow mansion.

Comment: Nice job!

Comment: HAHA @Nick D this is an awesome chop chop :D

Comment: Jeff should really do something about his prematurely-aged neck.

Answer (score 12):

Needz hornz

[Granted, it's only one horn http://img638.imageshack.us/img638/474/601pxoolonghorn.jpg](http://img638.imageshack.us/img638/474/601pxoolonghorn.jpg)

Comment: If we can get _two_ horny bunnies, we can demonstrate the Fibonacci  sequence!

Comment: @James: Um, I don't think it works *quite* like that. There's one important detail you're missing.

Comment: @James - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45238/the-offical-stackoverflow-bunny/45284#45284 above.

Answer (score 1):

**A [bunny-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463933/how-to-join-overlapping-circles/4464141#4464141)**