# Do you upvote/downvote other answers of question you answered?

Tags: discussion, support, voting

Suppose, you've answered a question and there are other answers there too.

As SE doesn't block your voting on other answers, I'm somewhat screwed. Your upvoting means your own loss in competition. And, your downvoting means fraud for own benefits.

Have you upvoted/downvoted other answers before? If yes, Why?

Comment: Competition? We're here to answer questions; forget about the reputation and you'll notice it just goes up.

Comment: Why its competition: Default sorting order is by votes. So, your votes can decide your position. Upper position means you'll get more upvotes. Now, don't say,you are not mad at gaining reputation. Think why SE has developed reputation fraud detection system.

Comment: This question seems a pool.

Comment: We can swim in it?

Comment: @kiamlaluno Please, explain..

Comment: @SachinShekhar: if you have a good answer, you'll receive upvotes. It doesn't matter how the sorting of the page is set (active is how I have mine).

Comment: I meant a poll. The question is, "Have you upvoted/downvoted other answers before? If yes, Why?" to which every user would report a different answer, and none of them can be qualified as the correct one. @JuanManuel Well, it could be a pool where everybody throws her/his own answer. `;)`

Comment: @sixlettervariables Check your statement here on answers of this question. How can you say, the answer with least vote poor?

Comment: @kiamlaluno Yes, its poll type question.. I think, normal QnA rules of SE aren't applied to Meta.X sites. That's why there's a discussion tag to collect different opinions..

Comment: @SachinShekhar: how can I what in the who what? I don't understand what you're asking. All I am trying to say is: you should not vote any differently just because you're answering a question. If you do vote differently, you're not being helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does answering a question lock you out of downvoting on other answers to that question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47886/does-answering-a-question-lock-you-out-of-downvoting-on-other-answers-to-that-qu), and [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28777/disallow-downvoting-other-answers-if-ive-posted-my-own) and all the duplicates listed there. (This has been covered a lot; you obviously didn't search first.)

Comment: Still, the "not constructive" closing question exists for meta site too. If a question is not constructive, it gets closed on meta sites too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Have you upvoted/downvoted other answers before? If yes, Why?

Yes, I do upvote *competing*  answers if they are good. I may even delete my own answer if better ones come along and mine no longer brings anything new to the table.

One can argue that voting on *competing* answers is encouraged considering the [sportsmanship badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/119/sportsmanship).

I tend not to downvote *competing* answers, but have no qualms over others doing so.

Comment: I'd downvote really bad answers to questions I've answered. But I haven't come across that yet.

Comment: @DanielFischer I tackle really bad co-answers with comments first. Don't recall ever having to resort to a downvote. Of course, if it's on a question that I have not posted an answer to hence not likely to drob by again soon, then a downvote it is.

Comment: If I think a comment may help, they're not _really_ bad ;) But if there's a chance for improvement, a comment it is.

Answer (score 17):

You shouldn't see your participation on SE sites as *competition*. It isn't. Upvoting someone else answer doesn't take away any reputation from you.

You are allowed to both upvote and downvote answers other than yours.

I upvote/downvote according to the answer - if the answer is good (as good as mine or better) I might upvote it. If it is a bad answer (incorrect, misleading or completely wrong), I will downvote it.

Comment: *"doesn't take away any reputation from you"*, not directly, but usually the most voted ones get extra up-votes (it's like who's rich is going to get richer), so up-voting another answer without having the same treatment back might be a drawback.

Comment: "_a disadvantage_" for what? Upvote good content, downvote stuff that shouldn't be on the site. Be happy.

Comment: I'm with Oded. Upvote good stuff, downvote bad. Heck, there's even a badge for upvoting lots of "competing" answers.

Comment: @Mat: A disadvantage for your own answer, that might be a good answer, but might get shadowed (I know thet are a lot og *might*, but it happens), the disadvantage it to the community not to my personal rep score.

Comment: I also can't stop myself to upvote a great answer, but @Rik is correct. Upvotes increase exponentially and visitors ignore low vote answers that's yours. What about this? Downvote can reduce your reputation, but you'll gain more by same rule.. so, its beneficial even after initial reputation loss.

Comment: @SachinShekhar - Not really. If your answer is so great, it _will_ get upvotes (people routinely upvote multiple answers if they are good).

Comment: @Oded I agree.. afterall its community, but -in practical - it matters on low activity SE sites where visitors of new questions are less than 50 for even month. As Vote/ visit ratio is very low (can be checked on SO too), votings are always low and this thing can decide fate. Anyway, your opinion is OK.. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't upvote other good answers you're just here for the reputation, and likely aren't helping people out as much as you could.

Answer (score 4):

This depends a lot on the site. For some problems there's only one right answer, so if I'm leaving my own answer I might be assuming all other answers there are wrong. But on User Experience and Gaming I find myself often leaving "Good Subjective" style answers where others have/will make good points in addition to my own post.

I don't see the voting as a competition, only the quality of content. You win by having the most correct or helpful post, not by the other people having less votes on their posts.

Comment: Don't forget, default sorting order is by votes. You votes can decide your position. Even here, you are less likely to get up votes.. its not because your answer is bad.. its because your are at bottom. See by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

No, not unless said answers are clearly wrong.

For programming questions (on SO), there may very well be more than one way to do it.

If someone else beat me to it with the same answer, I may or may not delete mine... or I may choose to add more detail to my answer.