# StackExchange Panda?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, fun, 404-not-found

Why is “[Panda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_Panda)” chosen for error images in StackExchange.com? Is this a new meme?

[404: [image]](https://stackexchange.com/404)

[500: [image]](https://stackexchange.com/error)

[site-not-found: [image]](https://stackexchange.com/site-not-found)

Comment: Hmm... http://failblog.org/2010/08/24/epic-fail-photos-slide-fail/

Comment: What did happen to the panda of 500? where's its head? poor panda :(

Answer (score 7):

Seems to be creeping up in several places:

[image: Panda]

Comment: How'd you find my exam?

Comment: Heh, saw this earlier today.

Answer (score 1):

Well, all good sites need a mascot.

Twitter has the bird, we have the panda.

Maybe we should name him! I smell a contest...

Comment: I smell a panda.

Comment: Pandas don't sparkle, say no to pandas.

Comment: Pandas? Pfft! [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45238/the-offical-stackoverflow-bunny/45243#45243) should be our mascot.

Comment: We already have a whole mascot *factory*. http://unicornify.appspot.com/

Comment: @Pekka: There's room for a panda too. After all, we have unicorns :)

Comment: Grooveshark already has Pickles the Panda. He gets blamed when there's downtime: http://www.flickr.com/photos/torley/3835388365/

Comment: My suggestion: Pandy.

Comment: Whenever I see a Panda, I am reminded of [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexual_Harassment_Panda). Please let's not choose a panda as the site's mascot