# What is the meaning of the "No pandas here"?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, 404-not-found

What is the meaning of the `Stackexchange` 404 image `"No pandas here"` ? I google it but I couldn't find anything.

[image]

Comment: Well, there are obviously no pandas on that picture (or 404 page, for that matter).

Comment: I think it's just a reference to the error panda http://stackexchange.com/error

Comment: It's obviously a reference to [animuson's website](http://animuson.net).

Comment: Also: [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60889/stackexchange-panda).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It just means there are no pandas here, and you have to look over [there →](https://stackexchange.com/error) to find them. Assuming you're looking for pandas.

Comment: ***&RARR;*** said the panda as he looked to the left.

Comment: @TimPost The panda on the left isnt really in a position to say anything

Comment: and since we are at it, just remember to [**NEVER** say no to Panda](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=never+say+no+to+panda), or we don't respond of any injury you may experience...

Answer (score 7):

Try

https://stackexchange.com/error
https://stackexchange.com/404
https://stackexchange.com/site-not-found

Compare with

https://stackapps.com/error
https://stackapps.com/404
https://stackapps.com/captcha

Notice any themes? Feel free to try this on other public SE sites (that is, ones with a unique design) and see what you discover.

(Apparently we don't need a captcha on SE.com proper, so there's one page 'missing' in the theming there.)